# what's the idiomatic way to store timestamp or time or date-time in datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I want to design one user registration table, 
in that i have to store registration time in time stamp.

so what should me idiomatic way to do that.?
i have two option in my mind
 1. either datomic instant valueType.
 2. simple time in long

or is there any other better way to do that.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: `:db.type/instant` is the way to go.

The long one: have a look at this blog http://dbs-are-fn.com/2013/datomic_history_of_an_entity/ to leverage native Datomic features: remember, Datomic is an accretive database so you have access to all the changes history so you don't really *need* those timestamps, that's more idiomatic and so recommended.

Comment: Agreed that :db.type/instant is preferred for this, but "append-only" is not the best description of Datomic's model (that's not how it writes), [accumulate only](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html#accumulate-only) is better. Note you can still retract things, you just retain history when doing so.

Also: if user registration time is the time when something enters the db, you can use history or the Log API for this. But if it's a different time, you don't want to conflate Datomic's db time and capabilities with the problem domain's use of time.

Comment: Agreed, I was aware of that, just copied blog sentence as SO style guidelines encourage but I personally like the suggested approach. Voted up!

Comment: thank you for clearing doubt about datomic idiomatic and explaining in a simple way...